# Build Windows software with JQuery

Tags: c#, java, jquery, eclipse, visual-studio

Is there a way to make windows standalone program which will have JQuery powering its UI? 
Since it will be a file manager, I would need to be able to access local files and folders so using HTML5+CSS+JQuery in browser is not possible due to limitation of access to local file system. 
I would be most comfortable using c# and VS2008 environment if possible. Any ideas?

Comment: Are you creating a [metro app](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/br211385.aspx)?

Comment: Unless it's a metro app, then no, browsers restrict access to the file system, and jQuery runs on a browsers engine.  You mentioned c#, why not just write a windows form app with that.

Comment: IMHO, Windows applications = XAML. period. HTML5 + css + jQuery + whatever can never compare to the power of XAML.

Comment: @randomus1r winforms is pretty much deprecated and not recommended for new projects anymore.

Comment: I am avoiding winforms and XAML because it is more of a proof of concept program and I think is it easier to create and animate elements with jquery. Metro App... somehow I concluded that it is not what I am looking for

Comment: @kush problem with Metro App is that it runs in its own sandbox and I would not be able to access all files on the computer, which is not very useful feature in File Manager ;)

Comment: @JakovDon I wonder if/how [this](http://www.windows8core.com/metro-file-manager-for-windows-8-offers-full-explorer-features-hands-on/) app works.

Comment: This was closed as not a real question? Really? I understood it perfectly and gave a pointed, accepted answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use jQuery in  [HTA applets](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms536496%28v=VS.85%29.aspx).

Comment: +1. You can freely use [FileSystemObject](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6kxy1a51(v=vs.84).aspx) from local HTA (essentially HTML file saved with HTA extension on local disk).

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov I think that is exactly what I am looking for. It seems much easier than developing Metro App. Thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

You can give a try to javaFX if you are ready to give a try to java. A sample DatePicker for JavaFX using jQuery UI can be found here [DatePicker](https://gist.github.com/jewelsea/1422815)